# Run F# script in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, f#, f#-interactive

I've been looking into running some F# scripts to automate some things. But I can't seem to be able to find a way to run the scripts. I've to an F# file.

Test.fsx

```
let helloWolrd = "Hello World"

printfn $"{helloWolrd}"
```

I know I can run it by selecting and running it with Alt+Enter but this just seems unpractical. How can I run an entire F# file in Visual Studio? Not by selecting the part I want to run.

Comment: You can run it with FSI at the command line. Not sure what you mean by "in Visual Studio".

Comment: Well for projects we have F5 for debugging. Crl+F5 For running without debugging. So that is running a project. To make it simple I want to Crl+F5(Run Without debugging) this script file.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted you can send individual snippets of F# files to F# Interactive by highlighting the lines you wish to send using `Alt + Enter` keyboard combination in Visual Studio. The same works with VS Code.

You can run entire scripts using `dotnet fsi script.fsx` from the command line. This works from Developer PowerShell within VS or other CLIs.

Comment: Thanks, it just seems very cumbersome to need to use the CLI every time. I saw a plugin "CodeRunner" on the VS Marketplace but it was last updated like 3 years ago. Is there no other way?

Comment: Typically I'll just have a separate terminal window open and enter the command once. Then to rerun it I just press `Up` then `Enter`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing, in order to write publish scripts of general utilities i use in my projects.

I wanted to right click on the script and get VS to execute it.

so go to
Tools -> External tools

"Add"

I did (obviously without the quotes)

Title <- "FSI"

Command <- "cmd.exe"

Arguments <- "/c dotnet.exe fsi $(ItemPath)"

Initial directory <- "$(ItemDir)"

Use Output window <- Yes

Now I can right click on the item and run it.

(strangely I think ive done something like this before and it was much more complex...but this seems much easier - maybe MS has made it simpler)